# What is Spring's SecurityContext behavior in terms of threads or different requests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, web-applications

I am going through different class implementations of Spring Security. I know that we set the **Authentication** object into **SecurityContext** ThreadLocal object as:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upat = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

upat.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(upat);
```

So, basically for each thread there is a separate copy of SecurityContext ThreadLocal object which holds the Authentication object for that thread. Fine till here. I have SessionCreationPolicy set to Stateless in my SecurityConfiguration as well. Below is the security configuration:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        final CorsConfigurer<HttpSecurity> cors = http.csrf().disable().cors().configurationSource(source);

        final ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry exp =
                cors.and().authorizeRequests();

        exp.antMatchers("/getJWTToken/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();

        exp.and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint())
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        ;

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        http.addFilterBefore(authRequestFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

But, I am confused about what does 'threads' mean here?

1. Do they mean, individual HTTP requests without having anything to do with session i.e. for each HTTP request there will be a new ThreadLocal Authentication object?
2. Or, is it specific to an HTTP Session? i.e. for a user's session, there will be only one thread and hence one Security Context?

I have these two doubts as well for both the above points.

1. For 1 above, if it changes with each request, then why do we need to check for Authentication object in each request's thread as below. I mean, if it is a different thread, there is no need of this. It will definitely be null. (The below if condition exists in the application I am referring to).

```
if( SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null ) {
    if( jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userObj) )
    {
        if( userObj == null )
        {
            response.setStatus(401);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upat = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userObj, null,userObj.getAuthorities());

            upat.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
            // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
            // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(upat);
        }
    }
}
```

2. For 2 above, if I have SessionCreationPolicy as stateless in my Security Config class then again, there is no session, but different requests on different threads.

I may be wrong in my interpretation of threads(ThreadLocal SecurityContext) here.
Need help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[SecurityContextHolder, SecurityContext and Authentication Objects](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/overall-architecture.html#securitycontextholder-securitycontext-and-authentication-objects)**

By default, the `SecurityContextHolder` uses a `ThreadLocal` to store these details, which means that the security context is always available to methods in the *same thread of execution*. Using a `ThreadLocal` in this way is `quite safe if care is taken to clear the thread after the present principal’s request is processed`. Of course, Spring Security takes care of this for you automatically so there is no need to worry about it.

Some applications aren’t entirely suitable for using a `ThreadLocal`, because of the specific way they work with threads. For example, a Swing client might want all threads in a Java Virtual Machine to use the same security context. `SecurityContextHolder` can be configured with a strategy on startup to specify how you would like the context to be stored. For a standalone application you would use the `SecurityContextHolder.MODE_GLOBAL` strategy. Other applications might want to have threads spawned by the secure thread also assume the same security identity. This is achieved by using `SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`. You can change the mode from the default `SecurityContextHolder.MODE_THREADLOCAL` in two ways.

The first is to set a system property, the second is to call a static method on `SecurityContextHolder`. Most applications won’t need to change from the default, but if you do, take a look at the JavaDoc for SecurityContextHolder to learn more.

---

**[Storing the SecurityContext between requests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/overall-architecture.html#tech-intro-sec-context-persistence)**

In Spring Security, the responsibility for storing the `SecurityContext` between requests falls to the `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`, which by default stores the context as an `HttpSession` attribute between *HTTP requests*. It restores the context to the `SecurityContextHolder` for each request and, crucially, *clears the SecurityContextHolder when the request completes*

Many other types of applications (for example, a **stateless RESTful** web service) do not use *HTTP sessions and will re-authenticate on every request*. However, it is still important that the `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` is included in the chain to make sure that the `SecurityContextHolder` is cleared after each request.

---

**sessionManagement**

```
.sessionManagement()
     .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

will lead to Spring Security using a `NullSecurityContextRepository`, instead of the default `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`.

It is a simple implementation, in that it will simply not save anything to the HTTP Session and, for every request, *create a completely new and empty SecurityContext*, hence with no stored authentication etc.

---

**UPDATE**

> That means, the below condition is always true if session policy is
> stateless. if( SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
> == null )

Yes, you will get the authentication as null unless you have set it before the condition gets invoked. In case you are using the JWT token, you can verify the same as below and can set the security context.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    String jwt = resolveToken(httpServletRequest);

    if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && this.tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
        Authentication authentication = this.tokenProvider.getAuthentication(jwt);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        ...
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}

private String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request){
    String bearerToken = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        return bearerToken.substring(7);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That means, the below condition is always true if session policy is stateless.


      if( SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null )

Comment: Hello Ashish, I have added more details on the same.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. So, if in case, the SecurityContext is not null, then, will the incoming request having Bearer token be authenticated with the Authentication object provided by SecurityContextHolder once the request reaches UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter by skipping the if condition. If so, how will UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authenticate it. Or, will UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter see if there is any Authentication object in SecurityContextHolder, it will automatically consider it authenticated? And, send request ahead to the filters remainining in the chain.

Comment: Ideally, there will be the jwt token that has been passed along with the request and you will extract and verify the token and will set the Authentication in a security context. *Authentication object in SecurityContextHolder, it will automatically consider it authenticated?* In that case, it may override the details.

Answer (score 2):

1. Without knowing where this if statement is happening, it's hard to comment on whether it's needless. If a request does not require authentication, the authentication may be null, but there may be other cases.

   If a request does require authentication, then once your servlet is invoked, the authentication should not be null.
2. Threads are not tied to a given user session. With Servlets, a thread is assigned from a thread pool to each HTTP request.

   The `SecurityContextHolder` is re-established for each request, either by pulling the existing authentication from the session or, in your case, from the request data.

Comment: Hey, many thanks for the spring security course on O'Reilly. It was so full of knowledge.